# Cannot run Gnat Studio

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm trying to run Gnat Studio on Ubuntu 22.04 but I get the following error:

`/opt/gnatstudio/bin/gnatstudio_exe: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have installed it via the following steps:

- Downloaded the "x86 GNU Linux (64 bits)" community edition and ran this
- Ran `/opt/GNAT/2021/doinstall`
- Ran `/opt/gnatstudio/bin/gnatstudio` and got the above error (sudo-running this yields the same error)

I'm wondering if this is down to 22.04 being a very recent release and some shared libraries are missing from the installation bundle?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're missing [libtinfo5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libtinfo5). Just try to install it via

```
$ sudo apt install libtinfo5
```

Comment: See also [_How do I find the package that provides a file?_](https://askubuntu.com/q/481)